# LDAP usage with multiple websites, .NET, Java, and PHP

Tags: .net, ldap

The client I am working with wants to consolidate user profile data into one central location instead of having it replicated in each database on each web application.  I was thinking about centralizing it and using LDAP to access the data.  They are a .NET shop so should I use Active Directory with LDAP?  They also have a Java/PHP website that would need to access this profile data which is possible with LDAP, correct?  Should I go with a custom approach?  Are using customer accounts in Active Directory a best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Active Directory to store user accounts is a good choice. However, rather than exposing the AD to web applications, you can easily create an abstraction over it using the free Active Directory Federation Services 2 (ADFS2). ADFS2 implements the server side of the WS-Federation protocol. It gives you the single sign-on for free. Implementing client slide of this protocol in ASP.NET/Java/PHP is easily possible using some existing frameworks.

Comment: This actually is a very good solution from what I read.  Is this technology somewhat the same ideas as Shibboleth of CAS?  I'd like to know more about it, but I have never implemented it myself.

Comment: Yep, WS-Federation and Shibolleth are both examples of security protocols based on claims. You can start your WIF adventure from this free book: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28362